# search page that allow user to select between three types using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

i have a search page that include three types of search  and i want to filter the search upon the selecting types

- type 1 : by newest members
- type 2 : by specialization
- type 3 : by name

specialization table:

- specialization_id
- specialization_name

members table :

- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- specialization
- registered_date

but the problem that the first type work fine but the second it show all members not the selected specialization

the first query for the specialization is for selecting secialization from the drop list

the second is to join between the sepcialization table and the members tables
can anyone help me ????

## search.php

```
//************for specialization droplist***************************//
function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_id'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}
$outputlist = "";
//**********search by new***************************************//
if(isset($_POST['searchbynew']))
{
    $listnew = $_POST['searchbynew'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE registered_date!='' ORDER BY registered_date DESC  ")or die((mysql_error("Error in quering new members List")));

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $row_id = $row['user_id'];
        $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
        $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
        $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
        $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];

         ////***********for the upload image*************************//
       $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
       $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
       if(file_exists($check_pic))
       {
           $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
       }
       else
       {
           $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
       }

        $outputlist.='
   <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="23%" rowspan="3"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                  <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                  <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                    <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                   <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                  <hr />
          ';


    }//close while
}

if(isset($_POST['searchbyspec']))
{
    $selectedSpec = $_POST['specialization'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, specialization_name 
                        FROM members u INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                        ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id") or die(mysql_error("Error: quering thespecialization"));

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $row_id = $row['user_id'];
        $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
        $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
        $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
        $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];
        $row_spec = $row['specialization_name'];

        ////***********for the upload image*************************//
       $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
       $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
       if(file_exists($check_pic))
       {
           $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
       }
       else
       {
           $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
       }

        $outputlist.='
   <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="23%" rowspan="3"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href =              "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                  <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                  <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                    <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                   <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                   <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                   <td>'.$row_spec.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                  <hr />
          ';


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `WHERE` clause in the SQL query.

```
SELECT ... JOIN ... WHERE u.specialization = '$selectedSpec'
```